# PdfWriter and Events

Tags: itext

I want to create a PdfWriter Object and set Events for Header and Footer.
The problem is it works if I create a new PDF. But my problem is I already have a PDF in Output Stream. Please find my sample code below.

```
Document document = new Document();
    try {
        // step 2:
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("D://2.pdf");
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[16384];
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
          buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);           
        }

        buffer.flush();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,buffer);
        writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.PageLayoutTwoColumnLeft);
        writer.setPageEvent(new DossierPortalUtil());

        document.setMargins(36, 36, 54, 72);
        // step 3:
        document.open();

        document.add( new Chunk("testing")); 

    } catch (Exception de) {
        de.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally{
        document.close();
    }
```

If I comment the line

```
document.add( new Chunk("testing"));
```

I get an exception

> Exception in thread "main" ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.

Without commenting there are no exceptions but it doesnt add the Header and Footer. Any clues are highly appreciated.

Regards,
Tina

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 3):

Yep.

You're trying to modify an existing PDF with `PdfWriter`, when you should be using `PdfStamper`.

Adding text with a stamper is Far Less Trivial than doing so with `PdfWriter` and a `Document`.

You need to create a `ColumnText` object, and get a `PdfContentByte` by calling `myStamper.getOverContent(pageNum)`.

You add the paragraphs/chunks/etc to the `ColumnText`, and pass it the `PdfContentByte` (and some positional parameters) to draw the text.

Alternatively, you can create a separate PDF with your text (and anything else), then use `PdfStamper` & `PdfImportedPage` to import those pages and write them over top of the existing ones.  PDF page backgrounds are transparent until you draw something over them, so the text (and stuff) will appear over top of the existing page.  This is noticeably less efficient, as the second document has to be converted to a byte array in PDF syntax (if you're using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of writing to a file, which would be even slower), parsed again, and then added to the original doc and written out a second time.

It's worth a little extra effort to use `ColumnText`.

You'll also need to write your header and footer directly with `PdfContentByte` calls, but you have to do that already within your `PdfPageEvent`, so those changes should be quite simple.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I got it working. But now the problem I am facing is - It is not writing the header. Though I do a getOverContent an getUnderContent and then add tables but somehow the header is not being written. Any suggestions there?