# Passing a parameter to an overridden OnEndPage method

Tags: c#, itext

I need to pass a parameter to an overridden version of the "OnEndPage" method, when i declare the parameter i don't get any error but when i call the method it tells me that "cannot implicitly convert void to itextsharp.text.pdf.ipdfpageevent"

This is my OnEndPage method:

```
  public class pdfPage : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
{           
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc, int parametro)
    {
        PdfPTable headerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);

        headerTbl.TotalWidth = doc.PageSize.Width;

        Image logo = Image.GetInstance("logo.png");

        logo.ScalePercent(42);

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(logo);

        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

        cell.PaddingRight = 52;

        cell.Border = 0;

        headerTbl.AddCell(cell);

        headerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, (doc.PageSize.Height - 10), writer.DirectContent);

        PdfPTable headerrow = new PdfPTable(7);
        headerrow.TotalWidth = 570f;
        headerrow.LockedWidth = true;
        headerrow.AddCell(new Phrase("TIPO DOCUMENTO", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6f)));

        headerrow.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, (doc.PageSize.Height - 50), writer.DirectContent);
    }
}
```

and this is how i am calling it:

```
 var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 170, 10);
        pdfPage page = new pdfPage();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream( "test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        pdfWriter.PageEvent = page.OnEndPage(pdfWriter, doc, 1234);
```

Comment: These are two different methods `public override void OnStartPage` and you are calling `page.OnEndPage(`

Comment: oh i didn't noticed, i copied the first part from an old post, i'm no longer using the onstartpage method, i edited the post...thank you

Answer (score 14):

To further add to what Bruno said, if you want to add additional information to your `PdfPageEventHelper` you can just add additional properties:

```
public class pdfPage : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
{           
    public int parametro { get; set; }
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var page = new pdfPage();
page.parametro = 40;
pdfWriter.PageEvent = page;
```

Or just:

```
pdfWriter.PageEvent = new pdfPage() { parametro = 40 };
```

If you want to change this valid "per page", you're going to need to move your logic into this class instead of the calling body.

Comment: Yes, this is probably what Mariano is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`page.OnEndPage(` returns `void` e.g nothing.

This means that `pdfWriter.PageEvent = page.OnEndPage(pdfWriter, doc, 1234);` is being set to `null`, but `PageEvent` cannot be set to null as it is not `nullable` so it breaks.

It would work if method signature would be `public override ipdfpageevent OnEndPage`.
[Here is an article that deals with PageEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070809/pdfwriter-and-events)
There's a method `writer.setPageEvent();`

Answer (score 0):

You've made a syntax error in this line:

```
public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc, int parametro)
```

The original `OnEndPage()` method has two parameters. When you `override` it, you can only use two parameters. If you add a parameter, you don't *override* the method, you *overload* it. See the page ["Overriding vs Overloading"](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~charlie/book/notes/chap7/sld012.htm) found on the site of The University of California (Santa Cruz).

It is hard to understand what you would want to achieve by overloading the method, because `OnEndPage()` is called from within the core of iTextSharp. There is no way that iTextSharp can guess what `parametro` is about. You'd have to rewrite the internal code of iTextSharp to make it work.

As LUIFA already explained, this is also wrong:

```
pdfWriter.PageEvent = page.OnEndPage(pdfWriter, doc, 1234);
```

It should be:

```
pdfWriter.PageEvent = page;
```

However: whatever happens, your overloaded version of the `OnEndPage()` method **will never be called** for reasons that should be obvious for those who understand the difference between overriding and overloading a method.

This answer explains that your code is wrong. You need to replace

```
public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc, int parametro)
```

with

```
public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
```

and replace

```
pdfWriter.PageEvent = page.OnEndPage(pdfWriter, doc, 1234);
```

with:

```
pdfWriter.PageEvent = page;
```

Now create a new question explaining what you expect to do with `parametro` because right now, you added this as a parameter, but we don't see you using this parameter anywhere.

Comment: Wow, this is quite possibly the most condescending and at the same time unhelpful answer I've ever seen. You didn't even answer the question.

Comment: Lol okay. Not sure how commenting on your answer is considered "trolling" but have at it.

Comment: I didn't downvote your questions. I downvoted some of your answers because I was working with iText and you happen to have answered most every question I came across on the topic. Some were helpful, some not. And it's not condescending to tell someone they are wrong, but it *is* to tell them that then refuse to help them with their actual problem. And I'm not going to assume you went and downvoted my stuff nor do I really care if you did, but I have a good feeling you did, so I'm not sure why you are whining and complaining to me if that is the case.

Comment: It was not clear what the OP was asking. Chris made an educated guess building on my answer. I upvoted Chris' answer. It is hard to tell if Chris' assumption was correct as the OP never accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class pdfPage : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
 {
    private long OrderId;
    private string PhoneNumber;
     //constructor
     public InvoicePdfEvents(long orderId, string phoneNumber)
    {
        OrderId = orderId;
        PhoneNumber= phoneNumber;
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
    {
         //Now you can use values
         //OrderId  And PhoneNumber
        //...
    }
}

public class CreatePDF
{
  private void GenerateCreatePDF(OrderListingInfo orderDetail, string contain)
  {
   var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 170, 10);
    pdfPage page = new pdfPage();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream( 
    "test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    int orderID=123456789;
    string phoneNumber="+01 123456789"
    pdfWriter.PageEvent = page.OnEndPage(pdfWriter, doc, orderID,phoneNumber);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this simple way and it has worked.

```
Have a class contructor
public class pdfPage extends PdfPageEventHelper{
      private int parametro;
      public pdfPage(int parametro){
         this.parametro=parametro;
      }
//.....
writer.setPageEvent(new pdfPage(int parametro));

//in the same class you can pageEvent
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer,Document document){
         try {
            //can access parametro 
           Text text = new Text(parametro);
           document.add(text);
         } catch (Exception e) {

         }
     }
```