# Add header using iTextSharp depending on page content

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using iTextSharp 5.5.9 to generate PDF. The PDF will consist of various images and a table. There will be images in first few pages (0 or more), followed by a table that may span in multiple pages.

Consider following test code:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnsCount);
table.HeaderRows = 1;

// Call AddCell columnsCount number of times to have the header row

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    table.AddCell(new Phrase(i.ToString()));
```

The code above will span the table in multiple pages. There could be other pages where this table will not be present.

I need to set header with a specific text only in the pages where `table` will appear.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

[Already Answered]

Oh, I simply [could pass parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24677744/68304) to the subclass of `PdfPageEventHelper`.

Comment: As you identified your question as duplicate, I marked it so.